# Typed arrays in QML? QByteArray to JS Uint8Array back and forth interop

Tags: c++, qt, interop, qml, arrays

Although JavaScript does seem to provide a range of type arrays for efficiently storing various width integer and real numbers, those seem to be absent in the QML implementation:

```
​var array = new Uint8Array // error: Expected token `}
```

I am in need of `QByteArray` interop between C++ and JS, and it is not as trivial as making `QByteArray` a metatype so it can be used in QML as a parameter - I need persistent hard copies of the data living in JS, although I will not be modifying the data from JS and will only be used in the exposed C++ API.

I currently have a solution based on converting back and from using `QString` and Latin1 conversion, and even though it does seem to pass simple unit tests, it feels flimsy and unsafe, so I wonder if there is a more elegant and cleaner solution? Also, it is somewhat inefficient, as it would use two bytes for every byte stored in it.

So it turned out that:

- as Mitch pointed out, there is a "ghost" character which messes up the code
- Creator's autocomplete doesn't detect Uint8Array, which reinforced my suspicion that it isn't there

This code snippet confirms it is there and working:

```
  var array = new Uint8Array(1)
  array[0] = 257
  console.log(array[0]) // outputs 1, the expected overflow value
```

But the significant part of the question remains unanswered - how to (efficiently) interop between `QByteArray` and `Uint8Array`. The key here is efficiency as I have plenty of those interops, and I'd hate to use something as clumsy as filling in `Uint8Array` by calling JS functions from C++ one element at a time.

Comment: Which Qt version are you using? http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/whatsnew55.html#qt-qml-module says it added support for typed arrays, though I can't find any documentation about it, unfortunately.

Comment: @Mitch I am using latest released version - 5.5.1, but the typed arrays definitely aren't there.

Comment: Would be nice if besides mentioning new features, they also posted links to their documentation and examples, but I guess that's too much to ask :)

Comment: I don't think the documentation is necessary, since it's implementing a JavaScript feature.

Comment: @Mitch - well not for typed arrays in particular, but for example for the previous feature an example or at least a link would be nice. Because as good as it is knowing about something new, it is even better to know how to use it instead of roaming the documentation in hopes of finding it.

Answer (score 1):

Heh, this is weird. Typed arrays [are indeed supported in Qt 5.5](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/whatsnew55.html#qt-qml-module). I had to ask a friend why that code didn't work. He pointed out that you have a [zero-width space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200B/index.htm) before the `var` keyword. I can't see this in Qt Creator, even with "Visualize whitespace" turned on, but `vi` shows it:

```
<200b>var array = new Uint8Array
```

He said it is often generated; perhaps by buggy editors.

The QML parser should pick this up though; see [QTBUG-51881](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-51881).

Comment: LOL, that's what happens when you copy code snippets from M$ :) Anyway, the typed arrays appear to be there, even if they are not detected by the autocomplete, as I get a 256 overflowing to a 0, however, a valid answer would constitute the `QByteArray` to `Uint8Array` interop part ;)

Comment: Sorry, I can't answer that part. Consider this as a partial answer that's too big to be a comment. :)

Comment: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-15876 for the lack of syntax highlighting.

Comment: A zero-width space?? LOL. I've missed such a nice new feature in the "New feature" section.  Oh well, better late than never. :)

Where's my `QMetaType::QByteArray` [here](http://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtdeclarative/src/qml/compiler/qqmltypecompiler.cpp.html#598)? :( [Yes, this comment is useless, shame on me, but shit happens]

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo auto conversion would be nice, alas, even if I post a feature request today, it won't likely materialize before Qt 6 :)

Comment: Also my BAD for "blaming" M$, this time for once it wasn't them, I mistook it for MSDN, but it was MDN - mozilla dev network

Comment: LOL(2). Some Mozilla fun would rip you apart for that. :P

Comment: Their efforts will be better spent on fixing their code snippets

Comment: Ah, that's for sure. :)